# Why my array element is re-declaring?

Tags: php, arrays

I have declared static array $error whose elements are defining in function validate

```
static $error = array();

if(!empty($_POST) && validate())
{
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table-name` SET category = " . $_POST['category'] . ", brand = " . $_POST['brand'] . ", product = '" . $_POST['p_name'] . "', location = " . $_POST['location'] . ", image = '" . $_POST['image'] . "', sku = '" . $_POST['sku'] . "'");            
}

function validate() 
{
    if ((strlen($_POST['p_name']) < 3) || (strlen($_POST['p_name']) > 32)) 
    {
         $error["p_name"] = "Please enter Vendor name of 3 to 32 characters." ;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

but the problem is when i am using the updated $error element like $error['p_name'] in below html, it is showing undefined index p_name.

```
<td>
    <?php if(isset($error["p_name"])){ ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error["p_name"]; ?></span><?php } ?>
</td>
```

and when I print `$error['p_name']` element within validate function it get printed with updated value.

Actually element - `$error['p_name']` in validate function is defining a new element rather than creating a new array element of predefined `$error` array.

Comment: You need to remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: i have already tried it.. removing static gives same result

Comment: Are you trying to use `$error` array inside your `validate()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you didn't answer my comment. so it was the **scope issue** , Do not use **global** keyword. Use the **Dependency Injection** concept..

Pass your `$error` array variable as a reference to your function..

```
function validate(&$error)  //<---- Like that. (See the & ?)
{
```

and when you do a call to your `validate` function make sure you pass the array too.

#### [The reason you should really avoid using globals. Read this linked article.](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it)

Comment: @user3588887, Your welcome. Never use globals on any of your code. Its really good that you noted the point.

Answer (score 1):

use global keyword to tell php, that you are using global $error:

```
function validate() 
{
    global $error;
    if ((strlen($_POST['p_name']) < 3) || (strlen($_POST['p_name']) > 32)) 
    {
         $error["p_name"] = "Please enter Vendor name of 3 to 32 characters." ;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, you saved time, actually i didn't want to use javascript for validations..